# Is it true that windows uses intel assembly while *nix uses at&t?

Tags: assembly

Am I right to say so?This is based on my own experience of disasembling binaries on linux and windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the debugger who chooses which assembly syntax it want's to display and not the Operating System. Usually, Windows debuggers go for the Intel syntax, and Linux debuggers rather AT&T.

**However**, some debuggers let you choose the syntax. For instance, GDB let's you switch to Intel with: `set disassembly-flavor intel`

Answer (score 3):

This is true, but only because of the tools you have chosen to use. The *machine language* is identical for the CPU (Intel x86, presumably), but the tools you're using might show the *assembly language* differently. The assembly language is only a human-readable representation of the machine language.

One might compare this to doing accounting in English vs. French. The *numbers* are the same, but the words used to describe the numbers are different.

Answer (score -1):

Mainly yes, but also depends on the assembler, for instance :

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_assembly_language#Syntax